# Checkbox is over text, how to add padding?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a listview with checkboxes:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nomeAPP" style="?listItem" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But the problem is: checkboxes is over text (text is to much for the left)

How can I correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting `android:paddingLeft="xdp"` where is x is the number of dp that you will need to put in order to you text?

Putting padding will only shift text but not your "Tick-Button". 
You may consider `android:gravity` property too if putting a hard-coded dp doesn't suit your need.

Comment: I eventually solve my problem using paddingLeft="8 mm" thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your text is in the same layout of the checkbox, do it like this:

```
<CheckBox 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:id="@+id/nomeAPP" 
      style="?listItem"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

But if its not, do it like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/nomeAPP" 
        style="?listItem" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Obs: I've put margin and padding with left only for the example.**

Let me know if you have more doubts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I used for items in a list, each of which has text and a radio button. Note the layout_weight and layout_gravity settings:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/select_file_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="100"
        />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/file_item_checked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to resolve this issue_

1 Building your own custom CheckBox Class by extending `android.widget.CheckBox` class. The Complete Custom code is as below_

```
public class CustomCheckBox extends CheckBox {

public CustomCheckBox(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public int getCompoundPaddingLeft() {
    final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
     /*add padding you needed so the text is not on top of the
      * CheckBox.
      */
    return (super.getCompoundPaddingLeft() + (int) (10.0f * scale + 0.5f));
}
}
```

2 Set Padding in Your Activity_

```
 final float scale =this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

 checkBox.setPadding(checkBox.getPaddingLeft() + (int)(10.0f * scale + 0.5f),
    checkBox.getPaddingTop(),
    checkBox.getPaddingRight(),
    checkBox.getPaddingBottom());
```

I hope this will help all who have this issue... :)